Slow Draining Bathroom Sink, help
My sink drains very slowly. It will fill up while washing your hands and take about a minute to clear. The tub/shower in the same bathroom drains fine. I removed the trap and did not find any blockage. The drain goes into the wall and makes an immediate right hand turn so it is not easy to auger. I am not sure if it is a venting issue.

Did you remove the stopper to the sink and verify the clog isn't higher up?

A common cause is blockage of the overflow channel at the top of the sink basin, which also allows air to escape: https://www.thespruce.com/the-purpose-of-a-sink-overflow-2718785 . Another possibility is blockage to the stack vent.

@UnhandledExcepSean Yes, I can see straight down through. I even put a bowl underneath and ran the faucet to ensure no blockages at the top.

@DrMoishePippik I rotated the drain and ensured that's lines up and it drained at the same speed. For the stack vent, would I have to snake that from the roof?

Even with that awkward right-turn, I'd try snaking from the P-trap, first. Since toilet flushes normally, the blocked vent is a bit less likely. But, yes. using a long snake from the roof has worked when I had an issue (messy rodent remains removal). Exercise care.

@DrMoishePippik once I get passed the 90 that worked great, thank you! Pulled out a pretty small hair clump but now the drain works perfectly fine. Thanks again!

@Austin. Great! You might write up the process of snaking, under that constraint, as an answer. It's OK to answer your own question. You might describe how you got the snake down that line.
